# How to write multiple paragraphs into one cell when writing to CSV with Python

Tags: python, csv

I have 2 variables I am writing to CSV with Python.
The data of one variable, description, are multiple paragraphs.
How do I prevent the new line to write to a new row?

```
from csv import writer
with open('test.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as file:
    thewriter = writer(file)
    header = ['Title', 'Description']
    thewriter.writerow(header)

    title = 'This is my title'
    description = 'This is my long description, with 3 paragraphs.\r\nThis is the 2nd paragrapgh\r\nAnd here the 3rd paragrapgh' 

    info = [title, description]
    print(info)
    thewriter.writerow(info)
```

Comment: this issue doesn't  seem to be connected to beautifulsoup? Just csv insert newline to same cell?

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh You are right, I removed BeautifulSoup from my description.

Comment: You might want to remove it from tags too. My goal however was that you'd make [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: This issue isn't related to `lxml` please remove the lxml tag - and make your code a _minimal_ example of just the problem you're facing with writing to csv - you can provide multi-paragraph data to `csv` as a Python string. See [mre]

Comment: @balmy Thank you for your direction, I have created a simplified example, and will do so onwards!

Comment: Your edited code works just fine on Windows double-clicking test.csv and the description is all in one cell.

Comment: @balmy Thank you, it must be the way I import it to excel in mac.

Answer (score 0):

The code above is working. Thanks to the guidance in the comments!